# React - add one more property to state

Tags: reactjs

So I populate the state for 'Sources' by fetching a list of sources from an api with axios. The resulting state of sources is an array of objects with some properties (see the screenshotp below;

```
const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
const [sources, setSources] = useState([]);
const [EndPoint, setEndPoint] = useState({
    headlines_url: 'top-headlines?',
    sources_url: 'sources?language=en&'
}); 


useEffect(() => {
        axios.all([
            axios.get(`http://newsapi.org/v2/${EndPoint.headlines_url}country=gb&apiKey=xxx`),
            axios.get(`http://newsapi.org/v2/${EndPoint.sources_url}country=gb&apiKey=xxx`)
        ])
        .then(res => {
            const newArticles = res[0].data.articles;
            const newSources = res[1].data.sources;
            setArticles(newArticles);
            setSources(newSources);
        })
    }, [EndPoint]);
```

What I'll be trying to do is to add checkboxes next to sources to indicate which sources to take articles from. First, however, I'd need one more property on the sources (Eg. active: true/false) to keep track of which source has been selected.
Would it be better to add one more property to the existing 'sources' object or create a completely new object referencing the sources id property? and how would I do it?

Thanks

[image: state]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are certain about `Source` `id` to be unique you can do what you're desire in two ways:

1- first as you said you can add another state which keeps for example `selectedSources` which is an array of `selected source ids` and you can add a source based on its checkbox to this array

for example something like this:

```
  const [selectedSources, setSelectedSources] = useState([]);

  const handleAddSelectSource = (id) => {
    setSelectedSources(value => [...value, id]);
  }

  const handleRemoveSelectSource = (id) => {
    setSelectedSources(value => value.filter(eachId => eachId != id))
  }

  const handleSelectSource = (id) => {
    if(selectedSources.find(source => source === id)){
      handleRemoveSelectSource(id);
    }else{
      handleAddSelectSource(id);
    }
  }
```

2- you can add a new property which will indicate if a source has been selected or not which you can do it this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .all([
        axios.get(
          `http://newsapi.org/v2/${EndPoint.headlines_url}country=gb&apiKey=xxx`
        ),
        axios.get(
          `http://newsapi.org/v2/${EndPoint.sources_url}country=gb&apiKey=xxx`
        )
      ])
      .then(res => {
        const newArticles = res[0].data.articles;
        const newSources = res[1].data.sources;
        setArticles(newArticles);
        setSources(newSources.map(source => ({
          ...source,
          active: false
        })));
      });
  }, [EndPoint]);

  const handleSelectSource = (id) => {
    setSources(oldSources => oldSources.map(source => {
      if(source.id === id){
        return {
          ...source,
          active: !source.active,
        }
      }else{
        return source;
      }
    }))
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you add another `useEffect()` and edit the *source* object in there. Use `sources` as a dependency in the `useEffect()`.

Tip: Enclose all the code in your useEffect where you call the API into a async function.
Ex:

```
useEffect(() => {
            const fetchData = async () => {
                axios.all([
                async axios.get(`http://newsapi.org/v2/${EndPoint.headlines_url}country=gb&apiKey=xxx`),
                async axios.get(`http://newsapi.org/v2/${EndPoint.sources_url}country=gb&apiKey=xxx`)
            ])
            .then(res => {
                const newArticles = res[0].data.articles;
                const newSources = res[1].data.sources;
                setArticles(newArticles);
                setSources(newSources);
            })
          }
            fetchData()
        }, [EndPoint]);
```